# hey I have a segmentation fault in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree, traversal

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<stdexcept>

using namespace std;

typedef struct node* treePointer;
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    treePointer leftChild, rightChild;
};

class stack{
    private:
        int top;
    public:
        vector<treePointer> st;

        stack() : top(-1)
        {

        }

        void push(treePointer ptr){
            st.push_back(ptr);
            top++;
        }

        treePointer pop(){
            if(st.empty())
                throw out_of_range("Stack<>::pop(): empty stack");
            treePointer temp = st.back();
            top--;
            st.pop_back();
            return temp;
        }
};

 void iterInorder(treePointer ptr)
    {
        stack st;

        for( ; ;) {
            for( ; ptr ; ptr = ptr->leftChild)
                st.push(ptr);

            ptr = st.pop();
            if(!ptr) break;
            cout << ptr->data;
            ptr = ptr->rightChild;
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        node a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7;
        treePointer ptr;
        a1.data = 1, a2.data = 2, a3.data = 3, a4.data = 4, a5.data = 5;
        a6.data = 6, a7.data = 7;
        a1.leftChild = &a2; a1.rightChild = &a7;
        a2.leftChild = &a3; a2.rightChild = &a6;
        a3.rightChild = &a4;
        a4.leftChild = &a5;


        iterInorder(&a1);
    }
```

I've been making tree inorder traversal by iterative. 
but when I called iterInorder(&a1), segmentation fault comes out!
In main function, "cout << a1.data" is printed well.
but in iterInorder function, "cout << ptr->data" causes segmentation fault!
please help me! I don't know why this happens

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `a3` doesn't have its `leftChild` initialized. So when following the pointers down the tree, we don't know where you end up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even without the `std::cout << ptr->data`, I have a segfault on Coliru. So your problem comes from other part. But when I comment all the `iterInorder` function, no more error. So you have a segfault in a call inside `iterInorder`.

When only the following code is executed, I got a segfault.

```
for( ; ptr ; ptr = ptr->leftChild)
{
    st.push(ptr);
}
```

And what if I print all memory addresses, so I know which one will fail.

So in `main`, it gives :

```cpp
std::cout << "&a1 == " << &a1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "&a2 == " << &a2 << std::endl;
std::cout << "&a3 == " << &a3 << std::endl;
std::cout << "&a4 == " << &a4 << std::endl << std::endl;
```

And in `iterInorder` :

```cpp
for( ; ptr ; ptr = ptr->leftChild)
{
    std::cout << "ptr == " << ptr << std::endl;
    st.push(ptr);
}
```

On a random execution, it gives this :

```
&a1 == 0x7ffe4ac6b750
&a2 == 0x7ffe4ac6b730
&a3 == 0x7ffe4ac6b710
&a4 == 0x7ffe4ac6b6f0

ptr == 0x7ffe4ac6b750
ptr == 0x7ffe4ac6b730
ptr == 0x7ffe4ac6b710
ptr == 0x10000ffff
bash: line 7:  5531 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./a.out
```

So I see there is a problem with `a3`, and that `a3->leftChild` doesn't give a correspondance to another known address. So let's look it's definition.

```
a3.rightChild = &a4;
```

Of course, `a3` doesn't have initialisation for the left child. So we go in a random address and it leads to a segfault. CQFD.

My dear juhong, what I shown you (or at least tried to show you) by this little post is the **art of debugging**. And by now, there are really good and usefull softwares to help us doing so. So go and teach yourself how to use them, it will save you time, so much time.

By the way, `using namespace std;` is a bad practice. As `Pierre Antoine Guillaume` said, if it's used in a header file, it will be used in the source file, and can leads to name conflict.

Comment: bad practice * because you are most likely writing your stack class in a header file, and therefore, the file including ``using namespace std;`` will also "use the std namespace".